# Do I have to run Corflags.exe again after updating the service executable?

Tags: c#, service, 32bit-64bit

I've a Windows service written in C# installed on a W2K8 server. This service must run on 32bit so I've used [`Corflags.exe` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms164699%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The question is: If I have to replace the service executable with a new version, do I have to launch Corflags.exe every time, or is the first time enough?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just do this correctly and use Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting?

Comment: Uhm... I get the same effect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CorFlags writes the flags to the executable, so every time you change the executable file you have to use CorFlags to set it for 32bit operation.

Comment: 2nd question :)

My problem is that I have to require Coreflags execution to administrators every time... and wait for them. 
If flags are written on the file... it means that I can launch COREFLAGS on my machine to set those flags? Or the command can be launched on "final machine" only?